# Failed to load images, server responds with 404 not found

Tags: javascript, html

What am I missing? Slideshow background function is supposed to use linked images to change the background. It runs locally but not when online.

```
    // Slideshow Background.
        (function() {

        // Settings.
            var settings = {
                // Images (in the format of 'url': 'alignment').
                    images: {
                        'images/4.jpg': 'center',
                        'images/5.jpg': 'center',
                        'images/3.jpg': 'center'
                    },
                // Delay.
                    delay: 6000
            }; ...
```

Calling JS in HTML file

```
<script src="assets/js/ie/html5shiv.js"></script>
```

Directory screenshot:

[image: Image of directory layout]

Comment: is the 'images' folder deployed to your server's hosting directory?

Comment: also check do you have correct extention for images? In my case, I had an issue: after deploying to hosting extention was converted to JPG

Comment: @Mart10 yes it is, as you can see in the screenshot; all the files I uploaded

Comment: Try using absolute URLs to the images, complete with the `http://`. If that works, it is because your images are not where Javascript can see them.

Comment: @Exit Just did that, still nothing

Comment: If you are in Chrome, try hitting F12 and look in the Console tab for any errors. If there are any, it may lead you in the right direction.

Comment: Whats the live URL? What does the rest of the slideshow function look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see from your screenshot, images have extension .JPG, but in your code you have .jpg.
So try to change jpg to JPG.

Comment: Did that when I added the absolute URL to link the images, as suggested by another user. It somewhat worked, I can see the images on my iphone but not when I open it on desktop (chrome)